# Regarding the Definition of an Orientable Foliation on a Manifold in terms of Transition Maps

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, orientation, diffeomorphism, foliations

**Introduction to the Geometry of Foliations**, Part $A$, Authors **Gilbert Hector** and **Ulrich Hirsch**, Page $15$.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a Foliation on a Manifold $M$ defined by the atlas $\{(U_i,\phi_i)\}$.

The Foliation $\mathcal{F}$ is called **Orientable** if there is a subatlas of $\{(U_i,\phi_i)\}$ such that all $\phi_{ij}$ (the tansition maps) coming from this subatlas are orientation preserving.

What do they mean by saying "the tansition maps are orientation preserving" (keep in mind, these maps are not necessarily linear)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a regular foliation $\mathcal{F}$ of codimension $q$ on a $n-$dimensional manifold $M$ the transition maps are of the form
\begin{equation*}
\phi_{ij}(x,y)=(\phi^1_{ij}(x,y),\phi^2_{ij}(y))\subset \mathbb{R}^{n-q}\times \mathbb{R}^q
\end{equation*}
for $x\in U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n-q}$ and $y\in O\subset \mathbb{R}^q$ some open sets.
The foliation being orientable means that you can find an atlas such that all the functions
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{det}((\frac{\partial \phi^1_{ij}}{\partial x_k})_{1\le k\le n-q})
\end{equation*}
are positive. Another, coordinate free way of saying that a foliation is orientable is to say that the vector bundle
\begin{equation*}
\wedge^{n-q}T\mathcal{F}
\end{equation*}
is trivializable.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the transition maps are of the form \begin{equation*}
\phi_{ij}(x,y)=(\phi^1_{ij}(x,y),\phi^2_{ij}(y))\subset \mathbb{R}^{n-q}\times \mathbb{R}^q
\end{equation*}

Comment: You are of course absolutely correct, thanks.

Comment: To be honest, the functions
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{det}((\frac{\partial \phi^1_{ij}}{\partial x_k})_{1\le k\le n-q})
\end{equation*} are not clear. How are they defined?

Comment: The $\phi_{ij}$ are the foliated transition functions, $\phi^1_{ij}$ denotes the part of the transition function in the "leaf directions" in the new chart, and the $x_k$ denote them in the old chart. Hence $(\frac{\partial\phi_{ij}^1}{\partial x_k})_{1\le k\le n-q}$ forms a $(n-q)\times (n-q)$ matrix at each point $(x,y)$. We then simply take its determinant of this matrix.